# What is buffer "target" in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

What is a *target* in OpenGL, actually? For example, in the function

```
void glBindBuffer​(enum target, uint bufferName)
```

I know what the function does (more or less), but the target was only a copy/paste enum value from a modern OpenGL tutorial for me so far. Can you explain what it *is*, possibly with an example where it is not just a copy/paste value in object load method?

Should I think of it as a variable of that name with some semantics, in drivers where you can put reference to a buffer (regardless of the buffers previous binding)?

Comment: I like the answers, but to address the last paragraph... I think what you wrote (in parenthesis) implies that a buffer can only be bound to a single location. One buffer can serve multiple purposes. For instance, you might use the same memory as a vertex buffer and a shader storage buffer. You can leave it bound to both of those targets simultaneously, which allows you to do interesting things like vertex fetches from a fragment shader. _Each target has at most 1 buffer bound to it, but buffers can be bound to multiple targets._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OpenGL specification uses the term "target" all over. It never offers a general definition of that term; consequently the definition of the term in general language is appropriate. A "target" in OpenGL is, as you surmise, simply a destination for something.

Buffers aren't the only thing with associated targets, though. There are targets for query objects, hints, et cetera. In most cases (all I can think of offhand), targets do refer to fixed, named "slots" in the logical pipeline and as such you will always be passing a particular enumeration value to a target parameter when you call into OpenGL.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

As per the [OpenGL 4 docs](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBindBuffer.xhtml),

> "When a buffer object is bound to a target, the previous binding for
>   that target is automatically broken."

Each target is a slot which can be associated with one buffer. Each target will influence which buffer is used by specific commands which come after.

(Aside: just now I grepped my own codebase, which does quite a bit of geometry & texture manipulations, and the only use of glBindBuffer it has is `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, x);`)

Comment: GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER would be a *very* common alternate buffer target, if you have indexed meshes, which you should :)

Comment: Originally, I though if there was an example(with some meaning except copy/paste) anywhere in code, the bind function from geometry loading is there just to illustrate.

Comment: @Babis you are so right! I just have triangle-splatter at the moment.